# How to get a Daily Market Cap using Python

Tags: programming, data, market-data, market-capitalization

I'm looking for a way of getting free historical daily market caps ? I can get todays Market cap from yahoo but need old market caps also.. thanks for the help.

ps: I don't have Bloomberg and school doesn't provide us with any data provider access.

Comment: Tell us, which market caps- companies or indices? What time frame are you looking for? Edit your question to give us guidance so that we can help you.

Comment: I'm looking for US stocks market caps for example 'Facebook' I know how to get the daily MarketCap from yahoo using the API but I want the historical Market Cap data and can't see how to do that and I have looked into it didn't find a solution ...

Comment: Check out the answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/587/where-can-i-download-historical-market-capitalization-and-daily-turnover-data-fo.

Comment: Already had and it's not working old solution ....

Comment: Thank you for providing more detail. I'll reverse my downvote accordingly.

Comment: I think this information will be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68985812/extract-datapoints-from-an-interactive-chart-using-python

Answer (score 5):

Tiingo.com has [fundamental data](https://www.tiingo.com/data/fundamentals) available through an [API](https://api.tiingo.com/documentation/fundamentals) you can access using Python.  I'm not sure if you have to pay for it or if it's included with a free account.  Either way, the outstanding shares are on the balance sheet within the fundamental data you can get through their REST API.

YCharts has this data on a monthly basis too. See example [here](https://ycharts.com/companies/MSFT/shares_outstanding).  From looking through the page, using Python `requests` you can get the data easily in JSON format and using the `json` package and use it how you like from there.

I just threw this code together as an example.  The output is a list in [unix_time, shares_outstanding] format.

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.get('https://ycharts.com/charts/fund_data.json?securities=include%3Atrue%2Cid%3AMSFT%2C%2C&calcs=include%3Atrue%2Cid%3Ashares_outstanding%2C%2C&correlations=&format=real&recessions=false&zoom=5&startDate=&endDate=&chartView=&splitType=single&scaleType=linear&note=&title=&source=false&units=false&quoteLegend=true&partner=&quotes=&legendOnChart=true&securitylistSecurityId=&clientGroupLogoUrl=&displayTicker=false&ychartsLogo=&useEstimates=false&maxPoints=880')
json_data = {}
json_data['MSFT'] = json.loads(response.text)
```

You can access the data by doing something like this to get the most recent data:

```
json_data['MSFT']['chart_data'][0][0]['raw_data'][-1]
```

Resulting in: `[1587686400000, 7583.4402]`

After that just grab prices and multiply by shares outstanding and you have market caps. You may have to assume that outstanding shares are only updated once per month unless you want to dig through EDGAR filings.

The above code is only an exmaple of grabbing data for one stock.  It would need to be altered a bit to make is usable for a list of stocks or list of dates, etc.  To get market cap directly instead of the outstanding shares just replace `shares_outstanding` with `market_cap` in the `requests.get()` call string.  The output would be daily market caps in the same [unix, data] format.

Comment: Thank you for your help. in Ycharts we can get directly the market cap daily (https://ycharts.com/companies/FB/market_cap) but don't know how to get it using the link request, can you explain how did you do that ?

Comment: @habdie Yes, you can do it that way if your goal is to retrieve market caps by hand for each stock. You asked for a way to get market caps in Python which is what my answer does if you make the substitutions I layout in the last paragraph. You can literally copy and paste my code into a python console and it will return the data.  If you want another symbol or list of symbols, you will need to adjust the code.  I assume you know basic programming.

Comment: can you please explain to me how did you get the link for the requests ? I want to play with it but don't know how did you do it ?

Comment: @habdie Right-click the table in one of the ycharts links and inspect the element.  Within the console, you can see the URL of the API that is called.  That URL is the one in my example above. Alternatively, you could scrape the page using python modules like scrapy or beautifulsoup

Comment: This was very helpful, I managed to get some data but when I try to get the max data it doesn't work always return the 5year data here's my link ;https://ycharts.com/charts/fund_data.json?securities=type%3Aindicator%2Cid%3AI%3A3MTCMR%2Cinclude%3Atrue%2C%2C&calcs=id%3Aprice%2Cinclude%3Atrue%2C%2C&correlations=&format=real&recessions=false&zoom=&startDate=&endDate=&chartView=&splitType=&scaleType=&note=&title=&source=&units=&quoteLegend=&partner=&quotes=&legendOnChart=&securitylistSecurityId=&clientGroupLogoUrl=&displayTicker=&ychartsLogo=&useEstimates=&maxPoints=824

Comment: can you please check if i'm missing something ?

Comment: @habdie I assume you are missing a membership but I don't know.  I'm not a ycharts user.  Give their free trial a try.

Comment: I'm using the free trial, normaly the link I sent before should get me the json for the full data but it does not ...

Comment: seems also like it's a default setting but dont know if i can change that ?

Comment: https://api.tiingo.com/documentation/fundamentals does look interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a source for Apple's historical market cap [here](https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/market_cap). Whilst this source doesn't have a hollistic view of all companies listed, I'm sure they're available just by searching and it appears to go quite far back in time too. I hope this helps.